# What are the "sneaping winds", and what is "put forth too truly", in Shakespeare's "The Winter's Tale"?

Tags: meaning, william-shakespeare, the-winters-tale

In the [second scene](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shakespeare_-_First_Folio_facsimile_(1910)/The_Winters_Tale/Act_1_Scene_2) of *The Winter's Tale*, Polixenes says:

> Sir, that's to morrow:
> I am question'd by my feares, of what may chance,
> Or breed vpon our absence, that may blow
> No **sneaping Winds** at home, to make vs say,
> **This is put forth too truly**: besides, I haue stay'd
> To tyre your Royaltie.

I was trying [to decode](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?Content=Text&WorkId=35&Act=1&Scene=2) his speech but to no avail.
Of what [sneaping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sneap#Verb) winds does Polixenes speak?
What is [put forth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_forth) (**offered?**) too truly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polixenes is worried that in his absence, ills may be brewing in Bohemia. Superstitiously fearful that those very worries might cause bad things, he adds a wish that his fears are ill-founded. He ends by saying that if not, he will have to admit they were well-founded. The passage means something like:

> I am worried that bad things could happen in Bohemia while I'm away. I hope that my worrying about those bad things does not make them manifest in real life. I do not want to have to say that my fears portrayed the truth!

He starts by stating his worries:

> I am question'd by my feares, of what may chance,
> Or breed upon our absence

He then hopes that these worries themselves do not jinx the situation in his country. *Sneaping* means *bitterly and destructively cold*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneap) has:

> **sneap**
> ***sneaped*; *sneaping*; *sneaps***
>
> *archaic* : to blast or blight with cold : **nip**

That is to say, Polixenes's meta-worry is that his anxiety might itself act like a cold wind, blowing back to Bohemia to bring about the destruction he imagines. The antecedent of **that** is **feares**:

> ... that may blow
> no sneaping Winds at home

And if his fears do bring about that destruction, then he will be forced to admit they were correct; that what they brought forth in his mind was in fact the truth . What is **put forth** is his imaginings, which turned out to be true:

> ... to make vs say,
> This is put forth too truly.

Comment: That's disappointing, 'sneap' is Scottish Gaelic for Swedish Turnip/Rutabaga, I was hoping the answer would turn out to be about the winds that some people find sneaps generate in their guts!